# Sketchup: copy, paste and snap (at the other end)

Tags: snapping, sketchup, copy-and-paste

In Sketchup, I can copy and paste some structure. Also, I can snap the pasted structure, but I wanted to snap it at the other end. How can I do this?

In other words, I can create a sequence of copy/paste structures, but I wanted a reverse sequence of it.

Thanks.

Example ok: Snap works, when copy / paste is from left to right:
[image: snap works]

Example does not work: How could I make snap work, when copy / paste is from right to left?
[image: snap does not work]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/163546/edit) and post a screenshot showing what you are trying to achieve, or what has failed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, some images as examples.